# ECharts how to hide pie but show the labels?

Tags: javascript, echarts

I try following this [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/echarts-3d-pie-forked-6d3z52) to make a 3D pie chart. But something went wrong when I set the itemStyle.opacity to 0.

[image: The example]

This is what it supposed to be. The 2D pie was hided, and the labels were still visible.

[image: My work]

This is the chart I made. When I set the itemStyle.opacity to 0, both the pie and the labels hided.

[image: My work with opacity 1]

When I set the opacity to 1, the 2D pie will overlap on the 3D pie.

[image: Official example]

If set the itemStyle.color to transparent, the labelLine will also be vanished.

How to hide the pie only???

```
// 来源：https://codesandbox.io/s/echarts-3d-pie-forked-6d3z52

interface IPieData {
  value: number;
  name: string;
  itemStyle: any;
}

export default class PieShape {
  distance; // 相机距离
  internalDiameterRatio; // 透明的空心占比，取值0~1

  constructor() {
    this.distance = 200;
    this.internalDiameterRatio = 0;
  }

  SetDistance(distance: number) {
    this.distance = distance;
  }

  SetDiameterRatio(ratio: number) {
    this.internalDiameterRatio = ratio;
  }

  CreateOptions(pieData: any[]) {
    let internalDiameterRatio = this.internalDiameterRatio;

    let that = this;

    let series = [];
    let legendData: any = [];
    let legendBfb: any = [];

    let sumValue = 0;
    let startValue = 0;
    let endValue = 0;

    // 预处理圆环宽度和给数据排序
    let k = 1 - internalDiameterRatio;
    pieData.sort((a, b) => {
      return b.value - a.value;
    });

    // 为每一个饼图数据，生成一个 series-surface 配置
    for (let i = 0; i < pieData.length; i++) {
      sumValue += pieData[i].value;
      let seriesItem: any = {
        name:
          typeof pieData[i].name === "undefined"
            ? `series${i}`
            : pieData[i].name,
        type: "surface",
        parametric: true,
        wireframe: {
          show: false,
        },
        pieData: pieData[i],
        pieStatus: {
          selected: false,
          hovered: false,
          k: k,
        },
        // center: ["10%", "50%"],
      };

      if (typeof pieData[i].itemStyle != "undefined") {
        let itemStyle: any = {};
        typeof pieData[i].itemStyle.color != "undefined"
          ? (itemStyle.color = pieData[i].itemStyle.color)
          : null;
        typeof pieData[i].itemStyle.opacity != "undefined"
          ? (itemStyle.opacity = pieData[i].itemStyle.opacity)
          : null;
        seriesItem.itemStyle = itemStyle;
      }
      series.push(seriesItem);
    }

    // 使用上一次遍历时，计算出的数据和 sumValue，调用生成扇形的曲面参数方程
    // 向每个 series-surface 传入不同的参数方程 series-surface.parametricEquation，也就是实现每一个扇形。
    legendData = [];
    legendBfb = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < series.length; i++) {
      endValue = startValue + series[i].pieData.value;
      series[i].pieData.startRatio = startValue / sumValue;
      series[i].pieData.endRatio = endValue / sumValue;
      series[i].parametricEquation = this.getParametricEquation(
        series[i].pieData.startRatio,
        series[i].pieData.endRatio,
        false,
        false,
        k,
        series[i].pieData.value
      );
      startValue = endValue;
      sumValue = Math.max(sumValue, 0.001);
      let bfb = that.fomatFloat(series[i].pieData.value / sumValue, 4);
      legendData.push({
        name: series[i].name,
        value: bfb,
      });
      legendBfb.push({
        name: series[i].name,
        value: bfb,
      });
    }
    let boxHeight = this.getHeight3D(series, 26); // 通过传参设定3d饼/环的高度，26代表26px

    series.push({
      name: "pie2d",
      type: "pie",
      labelLine: {
        length: 50,
        length2: 100,
      },
      startAngle: -20, // 起始角度，支持范围[0, 360]。
      clockwise: false, // 饼图的扇区是否是顺时针排布。上述这两项配置主要是为了对齐3d的样式
      // radius: ["50%", "50%"],
      // center: ["50%", "50%"],
      data: pieData,
      itemStyle: {
        opacity: 1,
      },
    });

    // 准备待返回的配置项，把准备好的 legendData、series 传入。
    let option = {
      // 不需要legend
      // legend: {
      //   data: legendData,
      //   orient: "horizontal",
      //   left: 10,
      //   top: 10,
      //   itemGap: 10,
      //   textStyle: {
      //     color: "#A1E2FF",
      //   },
      //   show: true,
      //   icon: "circle",
      //   formatter: function (param: any) {
      //     let item = legendBfb.filter((item: any) => item.name == param)[0];
      //     let bfs = that.fomatFloat(item.value * 100, 2) + "%";
      //     return `${item.name}  ${bfs}`;
      //   },
      // },
      labelLine: {
        show: true,
        lineStyle: {
          // color: "rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)",
        },
      },
      label: {
        show: true,
        position: "outside",
        rich: {
          b: {
            color: "rgba(186, 195, 196, 1)",
            fontSize: 26,
            lineHeight: 26,
          },
          c: {
            fontSize: 26,
            lineHeight: 26,
          },
        },
        formatter: "{b|{b} }{c|{c}}",
      },
      tooltip: {
        formatter: (params: any) => {
          if (
            params.seriesName !== "mouseoutSeries" &&
            params.seriesName !== "pie2d"
          ) {
            let bfb = (
              (option.series[params.seriesIndex].pieData.endRatio -
                option.series[params.seriesIndex].pieData.startRatio) *
              100
            ).toFixed(2);
            return (
              `${params.seriesName}<br/>` +
              `<span style="display:inline-block;margin-right:5px;border-radius:10px;width:10px;height:10px;background-color:${params.color};"></span>` +
              `${bfb}%`
            );
          }
        },
      },
      xAxis3D: {
        min: -1,
        max: 1,
      },
      yAxis3D: {
        min: -1,
        max: 1,
      },
      zAxis3D: {
        min: -1,
        max: 1,
      },
      grid3D: {
        show: false,
        boxHeight: boxHeight, // 圆环的高度

        // 3d效果可以放大、旋转等，请自己去查看官方配置
        viewControl: {
          alpha: 40, // 角度
          distance: this.distance, // 调整视角到主体的距离，类似调整zoom
          rotateSensitivity: 0, // 设置为0无法旋转
          zoomSensitivity: 0, // 设置为0无法缩放
          panSensitivity: 0, // 设置为0无法平移
          autoRotate: false, // 自动旋转
        },
      },
      series: series,
    };
    return option;
  }

  AddEventListeners(chartInst: any, options: any) {
    // 监听鼠标事件，实现饼图选中效果（单选），近似实现高亮（放大）效果。
    let that = this;
    let selectedIndex = "";
    let hoveredIndex = "";
    // 监听点击事件，实现选中效果（单选）
    chartInst.on("click", function (params: any) {
      if (options.series[params.seriesIndex].type === "pie") return;

      // 从 option.series 中读取重新渲染扇形所需的参数，将是否选中取反。
      let isSelected = !options.series[params.seriesIndex].pieStatus.selected;
      let isHovered = options.series[params.seriesIndex].pieStatus.hovered;
      let k = options.series[params.seriesIndex].pieStatus.k;
      let startRatio = options.series[params.seriesIndex].pieData.startRatio;
      let endRatio = options.series[params.seriesIndex].pieData.endRatio;
      // 如果之前选中过其他扇形，将其取消选中（对 option 更新）
      if (selectedIndex !== "" && selectedIndex !== params.seriesIndex) {
        options.series[selectedIndex].parametricEquation =
          that.getParametricEquation(
            options.series[selectedIndex].pieData.startRatio,
            options.series[selectedIndex].pieData.endRatio,
            false,
            false,
            k,
            options.series[selectedIndex].pieData.value
          );
        options.series[selectedIndex].pieStatus.selected = false;
      }
      // 对当前点击的扇形，执行选中/取消选中操作（对 option 更新）
      options.series[params.seriesIndex].parametricEquation =
        that.getParametricEquation(
          startRatio,
          endRatio,
          isSelected,
          isHovered,
          k,
          options.series[params.seriesIndex].pieData.value
        );
      options.series[params.seriesIndex].pieStatus.selected = isSelected;
      // 如果本次是选中操作，记录上次选中的扇形对应的系列号 seriesIndex
      isSelected ? (selectedIndex = params.seriesIndex) : null;
      // 使用更新后的 option，渲染图表
      chartInst.setOption(options);
    });
    // 监听 mouseover，近似实现高亮（放大）效果
    chartInst.on("mouseover", function (params: any) {
      // if (options.series[params.seriesIndex].type === "pie") return;

      // 准备重新渲染扇形所需的参数
      let isSelected;
      let isHovered;
      let startRatio;
      let endRatio;
      let k;
      // 如果触发 mouseover 的扇形当前已高亮，则不做操作
      if (hoveredIndex === params.seriesIndex) {
        return;
        // 否则进行高亮及必要的取消高亮操作
      } else {
        // 如果当前有高亮的扇形，取消其高亮状态（对 option 更新）
        if (hoveredIndex !== "") {
          // 从 option.series 中读取重新渲染扇形所需的参数，将是否高亮设置为 false。
          isSelected = options.series[hoveredIndex].pieStatus.selected;
          isHovered = false;
          startRatio = options.series[hoveredIndex].pieData.startRatio;
          endRatio = options.series[hoveredIndex].pieData.endRatio;
          k = options.series[hoveredIndex].pieStatus.k;
          // 对当前点击的扇形，执行取消高亮操作（对 option 更新）
          options.series[hoveredIndex].parametricEquation =
            that.getParametricEquation(
              startRatio,
              endRatio,
              isSelected,
              isHovered,
              k,
              options.series[hoveredIndex].pieData.value
            );
          options.series[hoveredIndex].pieStatus.hovered = isHovered;
          // 将此前记录的上次选中的扇形对应的系列号 seriesIndex 清空
          hoveredIndex = "";
        }
        // 如果触发 mouseover 的扇形不是透明圆环，将其高亮（对 option 更新）
        if (
          params.seriesName !== "mouseoutSeries" &&
          params.seriesName !== "pie2d"
        ) {
          // 从 option.series 中读取重新渲染扇形所需的参数，将是否高亮设置为 true。
          isSelected = options.series[params.seriesIndex].pieStatus.selected;
          isHovered = true;
          startRatio = options.series[params.seriesIndex].pieData.startRatio;
          endRatio = options.series[params.seriesIndex].pieData.endRatio;
          k = options.series[params.seriesIndex].pieStatus.k;
          // 对当前点击的扇形，执行高亮操作（对 option 更新）
          options.series[params.seriesIndex].parametricEquation =
            that.getParametricEquation(
              startRatio,
              endRatio,
              isSelected,
              isHovered,
              k,
              options.series[params.seriesIndex].pieData.value + 5
            );
          options.series[params.seriesIndex].pieStatus.hovered = isHovered;
          // 记录上次高亮的扇形对应的系列号 seriesIndex
          hoveredIndex = params.seriesIndex;
        }
        // 使用更新后的 option，渲染图表
        chartInst.setOption(options);
      }
    });
    // 修正取消高亮失败的 bug
    chartInst.on("globalout", function () {
      // if (options.series[hoveredIndex]?.type === "pie") return;

      // 准备重新渲染扇形所需的参数
      let isSelected;
      let isHovered;
      let startRatio;
      let endRatio;
      let k;
      if (hoveredIndex !== "") {
        // 从 option.series 中读取重新渲染扇形所需的参数，将是否高亮设置为 true。
        isSelected = options.series[hoveredIndex].pieStatus.selected;
        isHovered = false;
        k = options.series[hoveredIndex].pieStatus.k;
        startRatio = options.series[hoveredIndex].pieData.startRatio;
        endRatio = options.series[hoveredIndex].pieData.endRatio;
        // 对当前点击的扇形，执行取消高亮操作（对 option 更新）
        options.series[hoveredIndex].parametricEquation =
          that.getParametricEquation(
            startRatio,
            endRatio,
            isSelected,
            isHovered,
            k,
            options.series[hoveredIndex].pieData.value
          );
        options.series[hoveredIndex].pieStatus.hovered = isHovered;
        // 将此前记录的上次选中的扇形对应的系列号 seriesIndex 清空
        hoveredIndex = "";
      }
      // 使用更新后的 option，渲染图表
      chartInst.setOption(options);
    });
  }

  // 生成扇形的曲面参数方程，用于 series-surface.parametricEquation
  getParametricEquation(
    startRatio: number,
    endRatio: number,
    isSelected: boolean,
    isHovered: boolean,
    k: any,
    h: number
  ) {
    // 计算
    let midRatio = (startRatio + endRatio) / 2;
    let startRadian = startRatio * Math.PI * 2;
    let endRadian = endRatio * Math.PI * 2;
    let midRadian = midRatio * Math.PI * 2;
    // 如果只有一个扇形，则不实现选中效果。
    if (startRatio === 0 && endRatio === 1) {
      isSelected = false;
    }
    // 通过扇形内径/外径的值，换算出辅助参数 k（默认值 1/3）
    k = typeof k !== "undefined" ? k : 1 / 3;
    // 计算选中效果分别在 x 轴、y 轴方向上的位移（未选中，则位移均为 0）
    let offsetX = isSelected ? Math.cos(midRadian) * 0.1 : 0;
    let offsetY = isSelected ? Math.sin(midRadian) * 0.1 : 0;
    // 计算高亮效果的放大比例（未高亮，则比例为 1）
    let hoverRate = isHovered ? 1.05 : 1;
    // 返回曲面参数方程
    return {
      u: {
        min: -Math.PI,
        max: Math.PI * 3,
        step: Math.PI / 32,
      },
      v: {
        min: 0,
        max: Math.PI * 2,
        step: Math.PI / 20,
      },
      x: function (u: number, v: number) {
        if (u < startRadian) {
          return (
            offsetX + Math.cos(startRadian) * (1 + Math.cos(v) * k) * hoverRate
          );
        }
        if (u > endRadian) {
          return (
            offsetX + Math.cos(endRadian) * (1 + Math.cos(v) * k) * hoverRate
          );
        }
        return offsetX + Math.cos(u) * (1 + Math.cos(v) * k) * hoverRate;
      },
      y: function (u: number, v: number) {
        if (u < startRadian) {
          return (
            offsetY + Math.sin(startRadian) * (1 + Math.cos(v) * k) * hoverRate
          );
        }
        if (u > endRadian) {
          return (
            offsetY + Math.sin(endRadian) * (1 + Math.cos(v) * k) * hoverRate
          );
        }
        return offsetY + Math.sin(u) * (1 + Math.cos(v) * k) * hoverRate;
      },
      z: function (u: number, v: number) {
        if (u < -Math.PI * 0.5) {
          return Math.sin(u);
        }
        if (u > Math.PI * 2.5) {
          return Math.sin(u) * h * 0.1;
        }
        return Math.sin(v) > 0 ? 1 * h * 0.1 : -1;
      },
    };
  }

  fomatFloat(num: number, n: number) {
    let f = parseFloat(num as any);
    if (isNaN(f)) {
      return false;
    }
    f = Math.round(num * Math.pow(10, n)) / Math.pow(10, n); // n 幂
    let s = f.toString();
    let rs = s.indexOf(".");
    //判定如果是整数，增加小数点再补0
    if (rs < 0) {
      rs = s.length;
      s += ".";
    }
    while (s.length <= rs + n) {
      s += "0";
    }
    return s;
  }

  //获取3d丙图的最高扇区的高度
  getHeight3D(series: any[], height: number) {
    series.sort((a, b) => {
      return b.pieData.value - a.pieData.value;
    });
    if (series[0]?.pieData?.value)
      return (height * 25) / series[0].pieData.value;
    else return height;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please share the code that doesn't work, or a simplified example that can be run to show the issues you're having. The link you posted seems to work fine hiding the 2d pie, and from just the images we can't infer what goes wrong in your code.

Comment: Your question seems to be missing some detail. If you want help with your code, it's impossible for anyone to help you if you don't show the code you want help with. In order to help you we need a [Minimal Reproducible Example](//stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) directly in your question. Please [edit your question](//stackoverflow.com/posts/76918230/edit) and add some code to your question.

Comment: kikon Chris Barr I write the code as typescript but the editor of stackoverflow seems not support typescript. :<

Comment: What if you make the 2D pie smaller and decrease its [z-level](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#series-pie.z) ?

Comment: I don't want to use any opportunity to find fault with your post, but the typescript you pasted exports the class `PieShape`, but there's no data, we don't know how to use that class. Instead of pasting the long code (although typescript was recognized all right) you could provide the reproducible example through a link to a forkable codesandbox or stackblitz.

Comment: Meanwhile, thinking about the basic problem as you described it in the title, in order to have the labels shown and the pie hidden (for a standard pie2d), you should add a `label:{opacity: 1}` after (or before) `itemStyle:{opacity: 0 }`. Here's a [modified echarts example](https://shorturl.at/rvZ29).

Comment: @MatthiasMertens's is a very good idea. You could try making a smaller pie2d and have the label lines extend more by increasing [`label.lineHeight`](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#series-pie.label.lineHeight)

Comment: @kikon You're right. By adding label:{opacity: 1} this problem have been solved. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem by passing

> {    label: {
> show: true,
> opacity: 1    }  }

to the pie2d options!